# Remove invalid form from formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a formset that contains five forms. Each form is simply a file input element. Say, there is some invalid form because a file whose format isn't allowed is being selected. How would I remove this invalid form from the formset and let the formset continues to be processed normally?

Note I tried `myformset.forms.pop(i)` but that led to *"index out of bound"* exception in the further processing of the formset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's the goal here? To only save forms that are valid and simply ignore those that are not?

If that's the case, then simply iterate over the formset and only save the ones that are valid:

```
for form in formset:
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```